# Change margin of X Axis

Tags: livecharts

Is it possible to change the white space (margin) between the plotted values and the edge of the chart bounds? I wouldn't mind if the bars went all the way to the edge. Thank you for your help!

Picture for reference showing 5 charts in a wrappanel with so much space between Y-axis and bars as well as between bars and right side of chart:

[How to reduce margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mr2z.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is not margin. It's because of teh values of the X-axis. you can set `MinValue`and `MaxValue` for it.

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:AxesCollection>
        <lvc:Axis Name="xAxis"
                  MinValue = "0">
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:AxesCollection>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

If your values start from, let's say 0, and you set the `MinValue` to 0, then the bars go to the edge.